# When is the correct situation to use 案外 or 意外?

Tags: word-choice

I think this is a question I should have asked a long time ago.. What is the difference between 案外 and 意外? What does the correct situation look like when using either?

Example with 案外:

> 人生は**案外**短いものです。ですから、こんなにも貴重な人生を、自分が満足できない仕事で無駄にしているなんて、驚くべきことです。

Example with 意外:

> **意外**なことに、とてもうまくいってます。

The English translation definitely didn't help me with this one, as both are "unexpectedly". Is there a certain degree that is associated with each?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've always thought of them in terms of their kanji make-up.

- [`案`](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%A1%88): can mean "plan/expectation"
- [`意`](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%84%8F): can mean "idea/mind/thought" (with the thought process maybe implying some subjectivity)

From there:

- [`案外`](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A1%88%E5%A4%96?dic=daijirin&oid=DJR_anngai_-010):

  > - "not according to plans/expectations"
  > - "[contrary to/against] expectations"
  > - often, but not always "disappointing(ly)"
- [`意外（に・と）`](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%84%8F%E5%A4%96?dic=daijisen&oid=00738200):

  > - "[against/not] what was [thought/expected]"/"(I/you) wouldn't have thought"
  > - "surprising(ly)"

Daijisen has some usage notes differentiating the two in the definition for [`案外`](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A1%88%E5%A4%96?dic=daijirin&oid=DJR_anngai_-010). I think it basically says:

- `案外` is used when expectations/situations turn out different:

  > 期待していたが、案外つまらない映画だった
  >   I had [expectations/hopes], but it was a disappointingly boring movie.
  >
  > 心配していたが、仕事は案外楽だった
  >   I was worrying, but contrary to expectations, the job was easy.
- `意外な`/`意外に` are used when the reality is different to what was thought, or with things that can't be expected:

  > 意外に時間が早くたってしまった
  >   Time passed surprisingly quickly.

Answer (score 2):

- 意外 "unexpectedly"
- 案外 "after all", "unexpectedly in such a way that something is inferior than it was originally thought"

> 人生は案外短いものです。
>   Implication: Life is thought to be long.

In your examples, they can be switched with some adjustment in the form.

> 人生は意外に短いものです。
>   案外、うまく行っています。
>   Implication: People thought it would be more difficult than it turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

「**意外**」 is used when what you're describing is unexpected.

「**案外**」 is used when what you're describing is ***contrary*** to what you expected and is most frequently used with adjectives.

```
「案外安い」 OK
「案外簡単」 OK
```

However, I don't believe that you can say 「案外に」 the way that you would say 「意外に」

```
「案外に安い」 NG　⇒　「意外に安い」 OK
「案外に簡単」 NG　⇒　「意外に簡単」 OK
```