# What is the difference between 以外と、案外 and 割と

Tags: grammar

I've been having a bit of trouble differentiating between these 3 grammatical points as their usage is quite similar and can be interchanged at times.

Can someone explain the difference with some examples?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you mean 意外, not 以外. Partial duplicate: [When is the correct situation to use 案外 or 意外?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6258/5010) / [How to say “surprising” in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17533/5010)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for :)